# Import scss file from another folder

Tags: import, sass, directory, path

I've tried several ways to import an scss file from another directory and it didn't work, here's how the directory is organized:

> ```
> --style
> ---pages
> ------_Home.scss
> ---utils
> ------_mixin.scss
> ------_variables.scss
> ```

I believe it should import like this (In `_Home.scss`):

> @import "..utils/mixin";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file in your utils folder named _index.scss
Inside that file, type

```
@forward "variables";
@forward "mixin";
```

In your _home.scss file, at the top, type

```
@use '../utils' as *
```

Your variables and mixins will be available in _home

What I would do, as you are not showing all your directory, is create a main.scss file in the styles directory, then  do this inside it

```
@use "utils/index";
@use "pages/Home";
```

Compile the main.scss file to css

Your utils folder should come before the pages folder

@Forward and @use replace @import

Answer (score 0):

Correct in the _pages.scss file the path to the file.

```
@import "../utils/mixin";
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, It doesn't work

Comment: What program do you use to compile?

Comment: I'd use an extension from vs code called sass compiler

Comment: That's the extension: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler
but I don't know if the problem is related to the extension